# Distribution of $\sqrt{X_{1}^{2} + X_{2}^{2}}$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

Suppose $\mathbf{X} \sim \mathrm{unif}(B^{2})$. Then $\mathbf{X}^{2} \sim \mathrm{Dirichlet}_2 \left( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}; 1 \right)$. I want to find the distribution of $R = \sqrt{X_{1}^{2} + X_{2}^{2}}$. I think it's supposed to be $\mathrm{beta}(2,1)$ or, equivalently, $\mathrm{Dirichlet}_1(2;1)$.

What I have worked out is that $X_{1}^{2}, X_{2}^{2} \sim \mathrm{Dirichlet}_1 \left( \frac{1}{2};1 \right)$. I'm guessing (but not sure) that their sum should be distributed as $X_{1}^{2} + X_{2}^{2} \sim \mathrm{Dirichlet}_1(1;1)$. Whether this is the case or not, I don't see how taking the square root of the sum will show this to be distributed as $\mathrm{Dirichlet}_1(2;1)$ or $\mathrm{beta}(2,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is a uniformly distributed random variable on the unit circle, then the pdf of $\|X\|$ is simply $f(x)=2x\cdot\mathbb{1}_{0\leq x\leq 1}$, because the length of a circle is just proportional to its radius.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like I was wrong about it being beta/Dirichlet distributed. I thought it would be because I read that for general $n$, the radial distance is distributed as $\mathrm{beta}(n,1)$. Is this a special case, when $n=2$?

Comment: For the same reason, the pdf of $\|X\|$ when $X$ is uniformly distributed over the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is given by $f(x)=nx^{n-1}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{0\leq x\leq 1}$.

Comment: Thanks; I didn't realize that it does actually work out to be a beta. Just have one final question: how would I work out the expected value of $\frac{|X_{1}|}{R}$. I'm reasonably sure $|X_{1}|$ is distributed uniformly over some interval.

Comment: @pidgeot: if $g(x)$ is the pdf of $|X_1|$, then $g(x)$ is proportional to the measure of the $(n-1)$-dimensional unit ball with radius $\sqrt{1-x^2}$, hence $g(x)$ is supported on $[0,1]$ and $g(x)= K (1-x^2)^{(n-1)/2}$.

Comment: The expected value of $|X_1|$ is given by the integral $$\int_{0}^{1}Kx(1-x^2)^{(n-1)/2}\,dx = \frac{K}{1+n}.$$